# Insert data in a 4D spatial column using Sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, postgis

My application uses Node.js (v9.3.0), PostgreSQL (v9.5.1.0) as database with PostGIS (v2.2.1) installed as an extension and Sequelize (v4.37.6) as ORM. I'm trying to insert a 4D data - with longitude, latitude, altitude and a unix timestamp - in a LineStringZM column but I'm getting the following error:

```
DatabaseError: Column has M dimension but geometry does not
```

After some research, I've found out that Sequelize uses the function [`ST_GeomFromGeoJSON`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html) to insert spatial data. However, this function seems to ignore the 4th dimension in my GeoJSON data, which causes the error above.

I suppose that a raw query using `ST_MakeLine` (with the appropriated input) instead of `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON` would solve my problem. However, is there an easier way or a more elegant solution to insert a 4D spatial data using Sequelize?

---

Aditional info:

Model sample:

```
const GEOGRAPHY = require('sequelize').GEOGRAPHY

module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  let Course = sequelize.define('Course', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    gps: {
      type: GEOGRAPHY('LinestringZM', 4326)
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'courses',
    timestamps: false,
    paranoid: false
  })

  return Course
}
```

Insertion code generated by Sequelize:

```
INSERT INTO "courses" ("gps") 
VALUES (St_geomfromgeojson(
  '{"type":"LineString","crs":{"type":"name","properties"{"name":"EPSG:4326"}},"coordinates":[[-44.058367,-19.964709,0,1521552190]]}'
));
```

The SQL above returns the following exception: `DatabaseError: Column has M dimension but geometry does not`.

Successful insertion using `ST_MakeLine`:

```
INSERT INTO "courses" ("gps")
VALUES (ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(1,2, 10, 1), ST_MakePoint(3,4, 10, 1)));
```

Comment: Anecdotally, I have found there are issues with the way Sequelize plays with geojson. In your case, it looks you have discovered a bug in the lib and may have to rely on a custom `.create` function that adds entries using raw sql

Comment: It may be a bug in Sequelize but not in GeoJSON. According to [RFC 7946 - Position](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#section-3.1.1): _"Implementations SHOULD NOT extend positions beyond three elements (...).  The interpretation and meaning of additional elements is beyond the scope of this specification, and additional elements MAY be ignored by parsers."_